# How do I get Docker to recognize ffmpeg?

Tags: docker, ffmpeg

My container is intended to be a celery worker whose tasks have dependencies on ImageMagick and FFMPEG. This builds without an issue. Further, if I run the (commented out) `CMD celery`, then celery starts without an issue. It then fails in finding ffmpeg.

The `CMD ffmpeg` command tests that and currently returns just `/bin/sh: 1: ffmpeg: not found`. How do I fix this?

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --update ffmpeg

FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /
COPY requirements.txt ./  
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt  
RUN rm requirements.txt

RUN apt-get install imagemagick

COPY . /
WORKDIR /

# Run celery.py when the container launches. Commented out to test ffmpeg.
# CMD ["celery", "worker", "-A", "a.celery", "--loglevel=info"]
CMD ffmpeg
```

If I instead do the following, it works:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --update ffmpeg

CMD ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the library wasn't being linked. The following works:

```
FROM python:3.7

# This below is sufficient by itself to yield ffmpeg. However, we want to use
# the jrottenberg version.
# COPY --from=mwader/static-ffmpeg:4.1.4-2 /ffmpeg /ffprobe /usr/local/bin/

# jrottenberg version
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
COPY --from=jrottenberg/ffmpeg /usr/local /usr/local/

WORKDIR /
COPY requirements.txt ./  
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt  
RUN rm requirements.txt

RUN apt-get install imagemagick

COPY . /
WORKDIR /

CMD ffmpeg
```